# Powershell script to check Bitlocker Status and email if Off

Tags: powershell, bitlocker

I am trying to make a script that will check the BitLocker status automatically, and then send an email if it is not enabled.

Here is what I have so far:

```
Get-BitlockerVolume -MountPoint "C:" | Select ProtectionStatus
```

That shows me the status, but now I am struggling to process the output. I've tried doing it like this:

```
$OutputVariable = (Get-BitlockerVolume -MountPoint "C:" | Select 
ProtectionStatus)
If ($OutputVariable -like "Off") {Echo "Oops"}
Else {Echo "Wow!"}
```

Which should output me "Oops" if I'm understanding it correctly, but it keeps showing me "Wow!"

Maybe I am doing it wrong, so I'm looking for some guidance.

Edit:

Thanks to the comments below, I was able to make it work. Here's my full script:

```
# Bitlocker Script

set-alias ps64 "$env:windir\sysnative\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" 
set-alias ps32 "$env:windir\syswow64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"
ps64 {Import-Module BitLocker; Get-BitlockerVolume}
$wmiDomain = Get-WmiObject Win32_NTDomain -Filter "DnsForestName = '$( (Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem).Domain)'"
$domain = $wmiDomain.DomainName
$OutputVariable = (ps64 {Get-BitlockerVolume -MountPoint "C:"})
If ($OutputVariable.volumestatus -like "FullyEncrypted") 
{
Exit
} 
ElseIf ($OutputVariable.volumestatus -NotLike "FullyEncrypted") 
{
$date = Get-Date
$emailSmtpServer = "smtp.xxx.com"
$emailSmtpServerPort = "xxx"
$emailSmtpUser = "xxx@xxx.nl"
$emailSmtpPass = "xxx"

$emailMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
$emailMessage.From = "Report <xxx@xxx.nl>"
$emailMessage.To.Add( "xxx@xxx.net" )
$emailMessage.Subject = "Bitlocker Status Alert | $domain $env:COMPUTERNAME"
$emailMessage.Body = "Bitlocker niet actief op $domain $env:COMPUTERNAME getest op $date"

$SMTPClient = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient( $emailSmtpServer , $emailSmtpServerPort )
$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true
$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential( $emailSmtpUser , $emailSmtpPass );


$SMTPClient.Send( $emailMessage)
}
```

Comment: `Get-BitockerVolume` doesn't just return a string: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/bitlocker/get-bitlockervolume?view=win10-ps#outputs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PowerShell returns objects. You use the `Select` cmdlet to reduce the properties of those objects to ones you're interested in.

As such the following command:

```
Get-BitlockerVolume -MountPoint "C:" | Select ProtectionStatus
```

Returns an object with a single "ProtectionStatus" property and as a result comparing that to a string does not result in a match.

You can instead access the property via dot notation (e.g `$OutputVariable.protectionstatus`) to perform a comparison on its content. Alternatively, you could modify your `Select` cmdlet to use `-ExpandProperty` which will return the *value* of the specified property as an object of its type:

```
$OutputVariable = Get-BitlockerVolume -MountPoint "C:" | Select -ExpandProperty ProtectionStatus
```

Another way to achieve the same result would be:

```
$OutputVariable = (Get-BitlockerVolume -MountPoint "C:").ProtectionStatus
```

Here the brackets make the cmdlet execute, but then we use dot notation to just return the specified property.

Answer (score 2):

```
$OutputVariable = (Get-BitlockerVolume -MountPoint "C:")
If ($OutputVariable.protectionstatus -like "Off") 
{
    Write-Output "Oops"
} 
Else 
{
    Write-Output "Wow!"
}
```

Try this